# Display asterisks instead of bullets in password field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html page something like this.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <h1>Please enter PWD</h1>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In browser when i type in the password fields the values are displayed in bullets .. I want to have that in astericks (*****) . Is there any predefined methods in jquery or css style to do this ..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is determined by the browser itself. If you want to change this, you would need to create your own password control using HTML elements, which is not a good idea for security reasons.

Comment: is there anyway we acheive it using jquery keypress and using hidden values .. share those questions url which has been asked before ..

Comment: Yes there is, but as I said it's a very bad idea to do so.